# how class based views know that they need to call dispatch method

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

We know that `dispatch` is the first method that is called when our url hits the `CBV(Class Based Views)`. We also know that to call these views we have to call `as_view(`) with our `CBV` in our `urls.py` to make them callable.

`views.py` is shown below

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = "products/list.html"
    model = Question #Question is a model that is defined in models.py
```

`urls.py` is shown below

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',ProductListhView.as_view(),name='list'),
]
```

Now my question is

*How the `CBV(ProductListView)` knows that it has to call `dispatch()` method since we only inherited a generic views class but haven't mention anywhere to call `dispatch()`?*

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django Official Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#view),

> When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the
>   HttpRequest is assigned to the view’s request attribute. Any
>   positional and/or keyword arguments captured from the URL pattern are
>   assigned to the args and kwargs attributes, respectively. **Then
>   `dispatch()` is called.**

Which means, Whenever  matching pattern found the `URLDispatecher` sends the HttpRequest to the corresponding view and hence view calls its `dispatch()` method